# Unable to create a bot service in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

Whenever I try to create a bot service in azure I get an error

> "An internal error occurred at the server."

This error occurs when I create a new "Microsoft App ID".

Then I enter the password for App and chose "C#" and then tried with various templates like "Basic", "Form" etc..

[image]

Comment: It would probably help if you edited your question to show more concrete details about your app (perhaps even a screenshot?).

Comment: added the images to drive link here : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4MAdVeOCn5uQ1Y2WGxBMmRXMU0?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this, I think it was server side Issue, It's now fixed.

and here is a detailed explanation if anybody else faces the same problem.

[Solution](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52f62e38-bbfb-4b60-939b-f6e9e0fd01a0/unable-to-create-a-bot-service-in-azure?forum=windowsazuremanagement)